# Encode String to Base64 in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, base64

I want to convert a string to base64 within a msbuild target but msbuild tells me the type convert is not available.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Headers Include="Authorization">
    <Content>$([Convert]::ToBase64String(&quot;user:password&quot;))</Content>
  </Headers>
</ItemGroup>
```

Can somone help me?

**EDIT:**

Found a solution I don't like:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="ToBase64" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
      <In ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <Out ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      Out = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(In));
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="WebRequest">
  <ToBase64 In="$(auth)">
    <Output PropertyName="authBase64" TaskParameter="Out" />
  </ToBase64>
</Target>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: why do you not like the solution?

Comment: too much code for a oneliner and I would like to do something like this:     <ItemGroup>
      <HttpHeader Include="Authorisation">
        <Data="Basic $(EncodeBase64(&quot;user:password&quot;))" />
      </HttpHeader>
    </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use MSBuild property functions to do whatever you want. There are some limitations and one is that only a few namespace can be used. You have the whole list here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/04/02/msbuild-property-functions.aspx

Your problem is that you need the `System.Text.Encoding` namespace (to get the bytes array of your string) which is not supported.

As a proof :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Headers Include="Authorization">
    <Content>$([System.Convert]::ToBase64String($([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes("user:password"))))</Content>
  </Headers>
</ItemGroup>


<Target Name="Deploy" >
    <Message Text="@(Headers->'%(Content)')" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

fails with `error MSB4185: The function "Default" on type "System.Text.Encoding" is not available for execution as an MSBuild property function.`

but if you set the environment variable MSBUILDENABLEALLPROPERTYFUNCTIONS=1 then it succeeds :

```
D:\set MSBUILDENABLEALLPROPERTYFUNCTIONS=1
D:\>c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe test.proj
Project "D:\test.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
Deploy:
  dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
Done Building Project "D:\test.proj" (default targets).
```

For maintenance reasons, I would recommend you stick with your verbose task approach as this environment variable is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Since April 2022 support to encode/Decode Base64 is directly integrated into msbuild:

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/7554

```
$([MSBuild]::ConvertToBase64("text"))
```